# Improve worst case time of depth first search on Euler graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, eulerian-paths

How to improve the worst case scenario for a depth first search on an Euler graph, starting at some point and ending at that same point?

I need to do the whole search but it is not fast enough for large amounts of data. I have tried [bidirectional search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) but I can not keep the result numerically ordered. Therefore I wonder if there is any other good method to smooth the worst case scenario for the depth first search.

Comment: What is the goal here, finding an euler path? Why do you "need to do the whole search"? What does "numerically ordered" mean here?

Comment: Yes, finding a euler path that starts and ends at the same number. Each vertex has a number and the answer needs to be numericly ordered, assuming you start on 1, it can go to 2 or 5, you present the path to 2.

Comment: I'm traversing ordered lists with depth first search splicing subcycles into final result but it still exceedes time limit in one test so I have to make it better somehow :/

Comment: Is this for some kind of programing challenge by any chance? Is your algorithm slow because your data so large you can't fit it in memory?

Comment: yes it is for a challenge, the problem isn't memory, it really is time complexity, basically I need to make it faster to find results but apart from bidirectional search I don't know more ways to make it faster and thats what I would like to know if there are any

Comment: Why do you care if it's numerically ordered ? it might not even be feasible if that's a requirement.

Comment: Have you tried [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_path#Constructing_Eulerian_trails_and_circuits)?

Comment: @ Suresh
Yeah it is feasible and its a requirement.
@ Raphael
According to wiki, I'm using the Hierholzer's algorithm which makes it linear timed. Any way to make it faster?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what numerically ordered means. If you have a cycle on 4 vertices, where they are numbered 1-3-2-4-1, then there's a Euler tour but not one that's numerically ordered.

Comment: Depends on your initial graph, that would be correct this time since from number 1 you can only go to 3 or 4 and lower is the pick but, 1-4-2-3-1 would be an incorrect answer.

If it was a non ordered euler path, bi directional traverse would be trivial but, with order in mind it gets more complex since the bottom up traverse is hard to make ordered without messing up the top bottom traverse.

Comment: Even after reading the comment thread, I don't understand what you mean by “numerically ordered”. Please edit your question to explain (preferably with some well-chosen examples).

Comment: @d0pe, there can't be a better than linear algorithm visiting all edges of yur graph (if there was, it would leave out some edges).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the only way to have a numerically ordered eulerian path would be having a path looking like 1,2,3..,n,1. All nodes in the path must have degree 2 (since you can only get into the once), except perhaps for nodes with degree 0, that you can instead skip.

If this is the case, the algorithm would just be a matter of testing if the 1,2,3..n path is eulerian, with no need to find eulerian paths with a traditional algorithm.